# How to display the Binary Value of an Integer in PHP

Tags: php

How do I echo the binary value of an integer in PHP? I tried using `pack('S',$var)` but its showing no results...

Comment: Do you mean the binary representation, or the binary string of "0" and "1"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
decbin($number);
```

Returns a string containing a binary representation of the given number argument.

For instance `decbin(26)` will return `11010`

[Source docs for decbin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)

Comment: I guess he is more intersted by the string representing the number that it's actual binary representation (try echo decbin(9223372036854775808) on 64 bit system, or echo decbin(2147483648) on a 32 bit one. and for that base_convert is better suited

Comment: mathroc, I have no idea what you're talking about (ignorance basically) but the few times I've needed to convert those two types, I've used `decbin` without any issues. Since you seem to know what you're talking about, please provide an answer and I'll gladly upvote it :)

Comment: the answer from Chief17 is what I mean. it's just that decbin is limit to the size of C-integer, if you try the example in my previous answer, you'll find that it print "0". decbin works well but you have to be carefull of the size of your number (i guess little/big endian system could make a differece there too)

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
echo base_convert($number, 10, 2);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

`string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )`

Comment: +1 for generic solution and showing a little known function. Also, another option would be `printf("%b", $number)`

Comment: And if you want to store what @CarlosCampderrós says in a variable instead of displaying it, you could do `$var = sprint("%b",$number);`